# NSPredicate to return matches that all have the same month in the date field

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I am using `Core Data` and want to pull objects from the `Core Data` store that have a date object that is from `February`. It doesn't matter if it was February 2018 or February 2000.

Here is what I have tried:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF IN %@ AND dateHidden BEGINSWITH[cd] %@", itemsToFilter, yearString]
```

However, this gives the error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't do a substring operation
>   with something that isn't a string (lhs = 2008-11-04 00:00:00 +0000
>   rhs = 2016)'

It seems this would be possible if I could turn the date object into a string.

How can I write a `predicate` that will filter out only objects that have `February` in the date?

Comment: You surely tried *something*. Don't hesitate to show your attempt, so that this does not look like a “write the code for me” question!

Comment: @Carpsen90 Sorry, updated question.

Comment: Don't try to analyze a date in a predicate. You need to maintain a month attribute in your entity if you know you're doing to be doing a search like this. Or use a value transformer to derive the month number from the date.

Comment: @matt I am needing to add this for a production app so I would prefer not to have to add an entity for this and force a DB migration, which has failed in the past. Can you explain about the value transformer?

Comment: A value transformer is a simple subclass of `NSValueTransformer` which would convert your `NSDate` into an `NSString`. In your Core Data model, you can mark properties as "Transformable" and then specify the `NSValueTransformer` as the class to use to convert that property. With that done, you could then use a predicate as you you've shown in your question, as that `NSDate` property is now "transformable" to an `NSString`. But you still wouldn't be able to avoid a migration; I'm pretty sure changing a property to transformable requires a migration...

Comment: @PeteMorris but not by transforming a date into a string! There is a right way to derive a month number from a date, and that is not it.

Comment: Fair enough, but it may be more helpful to the person asking the question if you explained. @NicHubbard You can also parse the date for date components and return an integer from your value transformer which, as Matt says, would be preferable. Either way, I’m afraid you probably won’t be able to avoid a migration.

Comment: Assuming your dates are bounded, I think your best bet to avoid messing with the model, will be to iterate through the years, determine NSDates for the start and end of February in each year, and build a (very long and ugly) predicate, though the query might be slow.  Or fetch all the objects and then filter the resulting array in memory.